# How to make openGLView transparent?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, cclayer

I am trying to make transparent openGLView for my game, I want it transparent only for one feature within my game. Actually, it is a feature related with camera of the device. 
I am using UIImagePickerController for my camera, but I am unable to make the GLView transparent.

I have tried using Ray's tutorial, And I am posting some of my code here:

```
glClearColor(0,0,0,0);

[CCDirector sharedDirector].openGLView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[CCDirector sharedDirector].openGLView.opaque = NO;
```

Then I am having a UIView which I am adding as a subView to the UIWindow and then I am adding the Picker view to UIView.

Any ideas's on how can I make this openGLView transparent?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Please Try following code for transparent.

```
glLayer.opaque = NO;      
glLayer.drawableProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8, kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat, nil];
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

Comment: It says property "drawableProperties" not found on object type of EAGLView ..!

Comment: That's because glLayer is an instance of [CAEGLLayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CAEAGLLayer_Class/CAEGLLayer/CAEGLLayer.html), not EAGLView. CAEGLLayer is the layer in EAGLView. So just do view.layer.drawableProperties = ...

Comment: Okay ..Got it ..But now when I am trying to add some Sprites, Why is the background BLACK ..? I want to them appear on the transparent background